# Who is this apprentice?

Tags: grishaverse

In “When Water Sang Fire,” Ulla meets a strange apprentice seer, a mortal witch who tells her how to use a dangerous power. The seer claims to be her half-brother. However, he also seems to be significant in some other fashion, from this passage:

> “I must go,” he said. “I have my own war ahead, a long one. I am not quite mortal either, and I have many lives to live.”
>
> <sub>*The Language of Thorns*, “When Water Sang Fire”</sub>

This seems to be an allusion, but to what? Is he some historical figure or character mentioned elsewhere in the Grishaverse?